# MongoDB standalone vs replica set and how to migrate data from a standalone to a replica set

Tags: mongodb, replication, mongodb-replica-set

I have a few questions about MongoDB standalone and Replica sets, I don't really get it.

- When should I use either of them
- Why all the replica sets tutorials show 3 connections, is there a reason?
- Can I create a replica set for 1 instance only? and in that case how is it different than the standalone mongodb instance?
- How to Migrate data from a standalone instance to replica sets?

All these questions I'm asking because recently I was trying to implement transactions and sessions can only start on "replica sets" I don't really get the difference at all.

Comment: MongoDB resources answer most of your questions even conceptual pros and cons and an explicit conversion guide. Have fun reading: https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/convert-standalone-to-replica-set/

Comment: Thanks @Björn, this helps me convert (and probably migrate) but I can't find on this page anywhere that explains conceptually what is the difference between 1 standalone instance and 1 replica set connection?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

- **When should I use either of them?**

> Replication is the process of synchronizing data across multiple servers. Replication provides redundancy and increases data availability with multiple copies of data on different database servers. Replication protects a database from the loss of a single server. Replication also allows you to recover from hardware failure and service interruptions. With additional copies of the data, you can dedicate one to disaster recovery, reporting, or backup.
>
> - To keep your data safe
> - High (24*7) availability of data
> - Disaster   recovery
> - No downtime for maintenance (like backups, index rebuilds,    compaction) Read scaling (extra copies to read from)
> - Replica set is transparent to the application

- **Why all the replica sets tutorials show 3 connections, is there a reason?**

> The basic implementation to take full advantage of replication specifies you
> should have at least one primary node with two secondary nodes. So the
> examples are always with 3 nodes. Not only this if from 3 the
> Primary node goes down you still have 2 nodes (mongoDB will assign
> using arbiter rule) and one primary and one secondary for high availability

- **Can I create a replica set for 1 instance only? and in that case how is it different than the standalone mongodb instance?**

> It does not make sense to have single instance with mongo replication.

- How to Migrate data from a standalone instance to replica sets?

> [Convert a Standalone to a Replica Set](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/convert-standalone-to-replica-set/) . Your existing data will be migrated to all replication instances once they are up and running when converted to replication sets from standalone.